# Is there a command that does 'git [merge|rebase] --abort'?

Tags: git

I know `git merge --abort`, `git rebase --abort` are different commands, but that's sometimes confusing to me.

For example, when you have conflict while `git pull`, you have to see terminal logs or `git status` then read the messages to figure out whether or not `pull.rebase = true` is set.

Is there a git alias or bash alias that can do the following?

1. If there's a `rebase in progress`, then `git rebase --abort`.
2. If there's a `MERGE_HEAD`, then `git merge --abort`.

Comment: Maybe it’d be better for you not to use git pull?

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't, because `merge` and `rebase` are different `git` commands.